# How to use a if function as try except

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a program which has a loop in it.
In this loop I load images from a file. 
But there are some not usable images, that I don`t want to sort by hand.
I have this code:

```
        img = Image.open("downloads/parrot/" + pictures[i])
        img = img.resize((150,150))
        img.save("Validation/parrot/" + "picture" + str(i) + ".png")
        i = i + 1
```

I tried to use the try except method, but it always stopped the program.
Is there any way to use an if loop, like "if imageisuseful() = false:"?
Or do you may have any other Ideas?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: what do you mean by 'not useful images'? if you add some more context, maybe we can help.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your `try / except` to stop your code, you can `pass` :

```
try:
    img = Image.open("downloads/parrot/" + pictures[i])
    img = img.resize((150,150))
    img.save("Validation/parrot/" + "picture" + str(i) + ".png")
    i = i + 1
except:
    pass # pictures[i] raised an exception here
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where the error is happening (either at the open or the resize) you might need to move things around:

```
img = Image.open("downloads/parrot/" + pictures[i])
try:
    img = img.resize((150,150))
    img.save("Validation/parrot/" + "picture" + str(i) + ".png")
    i = i + 1
except:
    print("FILE {} DOESN'T WORK".format(pictures[i]))
```